# Dumping virtual memory addresses of an executable from /proc/pid/maps

Tags: linux, executable, proc, virtual-memory

I want to dump the virtual memory addresses of a running executable.

This is the command I'm running: `./executable & cat /proc/$(pidof executable)/maps > maps.dump`, and this is the error I get: `cat: /proc//maps: No such file or directory`

My intention of using `&` is to keep the `executable` running in the background so the process will remain alive and its `/proc/$(pidof executable)` directory will be still there when trying to access it to dump the `maps` info, but obviously it's not doing so since `pidof executable` is returning empty which means the process is no longer running.

Comment: Does it work any better if you run `nohup ./executable &` instead of `./executable &`?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use your shell's ability to remember the PID of the last process you've started in the `$!` variable.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
./executable &
cat /proc/$!/maps > maps.dump
```

A much nicer way of inspecting memory can be had if you get `radare2`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
./executable &
r2 -d $!
```

will drop you to the radare2 shell.

[`dm`](https://r2wiki.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options/d/dm/) is the command you want to run to get the "classical" memory map, `dm=` is visually much more helpful to understand what you're looking at, `dmd` dumps the debug memory map to a file.

You can, however, do actually useful stuff. Like, saving all mapped memory temporarily using `dmsa`, then fiddling around with process memory to your heart's delight, test what that does to the process and its behaviour, and restore if necessary selectively (`dmr`) or completely (`dmra`).